# Validate dataset using XSD file

Tags: .net, xml, ado.net

I have XML file and i am genrating Datset from it

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(strMasterSqlXML))); //strMasterSqlXML is XML string
```

I have XSD file and i want to validate that dataset set by XSD file to check datatype and relations, if it's possible by direct xml validation or by dataset i am ready to implemt.

Give me idea...

Comment: Do you want to validate strMasterSqlXML or what?

Comment: Actually i have to check datatype and relation if it possible by anyhow …I am ready….

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into JAXB. From your xsd it will generate java classes that you can uses to populate your dataset with simple methods. From there you can validate and write to an XML file with ease.

jaxb.java.net